# Return data from a call to a client

Tags: c#, signalr

I have a system connected to a digital scale and I'm trying to use SignalR to pass the weight into other requesting clients.

My Hub looks like this:

```
public class ScaleHub : Hub
{
    private static string ScaleClientId { get; set; }

    // the weight object for the client making the request
    private static Dictionary<string, WeightDTO> scaleWeights =
        new Dictionary<string, WeightDTO>();

    public void RegisterScale()
    {
        ScaleClientId = Context.ConnectionId;
    }

    public WeightDTO GetWeight()
    {
        // clear the scale weight for the client making the request
        scaleWeights[Context.ConnectionId] = null;

        Task updateWeightTask = Clients[ScaleClientId].UpdateWeight(Context.ConnectionId);

        // this doesn't wait :-(
        updateWeightTask.Wait();

        return scaleWeights[Context.ConnectionId];
    }

    public void UpdateWeight(WeightDTO weight, string clientId)
    {
        // update the weight for the client making the request
        scaleWeights[clientId] = weight;
    }
}
```

The important parts of the client are:

```
scaleHub.On<string>("UpdateWeight", UpdateWeight);

private void UpdateWeight(string clientId)
{
    // this is replaced with code that talks to the scale hardware
    var newWeight = new WeightDTO(123, WeightUnitTypes.LB);

    scaleHub.Invoke("UpdateWeight", newWeight, clientId).Wait();
}

public Task<WeightDTO> GetWeight()
{
    return scaleHub.Invoke<WeightDTO>("GetWeight");
}
```

I'm still new to SignalR so I'm not sure I'm going about this the right way.

Adding `Thread.Sleep(2000)` instead of `updateWeightTask.Wait()` solves the issues, since it gives enough time for the round-trip calls to UpdateWeight to finish. I'd prefer not to make my clients wait 2 seconds to get the weight.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why would you round trip this to the client before updating the state on the server?

Comment: The server/hub doesn't have the scale hardware. I need to request the weight from the client which has the scale hardware. Client A (no scale) asks server B (no scale) for weight from client C (with scale).

Comment: Waiting on the send will definitely not help you in anyway, that wait is only for the send not for the receive on the client. You'll need to implement a client wait yourself, which shouldn't be that hard.